# How to fix erlang unmet dependency errors?

Tags: apt, package-management, debian, rabbitmq, erlang

I am facing dependency issues while doing installation of `rabbitmq-server` through APT. I have 2 files added in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`: `bintray.rabbitmq.list` and `rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server.list`

`bintray.rabbitmq.list` contains :

```
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian bionic erlang-22.1
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian bionic main
```

`rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server.list` contains:

```
deb https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb-src https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

I have Ubuntu 19.04 bionic.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rabbitmq-server : Depends: erlang-base (>= 1:21.3) but 1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            erlang-base-hipe (>= 1:21.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-crypto (>= 1:21.3) but 1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-eldap (>= 1:21.3) but 1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-inets (>= 1:21.3) but 1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-mnesia (>= 1:21.3) but 1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-os-mon (>= 1:21.3) but 1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-parsetools (>= 1:21.3) but 1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-public-key (>= 1:21.3) but 1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-runtime-tools (>= 1:21.3) but 1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-ssl (>= 1:21.3) but 1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-syntax-tools (>= 1:21.3) but 1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-tools (>= 1:21.3) but 1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-xmerl (>= 1:21.3) but 1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not<br> installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
$ apt-cache policy rabbitmq-server
rabbitmq-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.8.0-1
  Version table:
        500 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     3.6.10-1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 19.04 has a different [code name](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) so I am going to assume that you meant to say you're using Ubuntu 18.04.

Carefully read [these instructions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html). You have to pin the Erlang version and you probably shouldn't mix bintray and packagecloud resources.

The following `Vagrantfile` successfully installs the latest Erlang and RabbitMQ packages. You should be able to adapt it to your needs.

```
$script = <<SCRIPT
apt-get install -y sudo
apt-get update -y
apt-get install curl gnupg -y
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rabbitmq/signing-keys/releases/download/2.0/rabbitmq-release-signing-key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
apt-get install apt-transport-https
tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.rabbitmq.list <<EOF
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian bionic erlang
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian bionic main
EOF
apt-get update -y
apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y --fix-missing
date > /etc/vagrant_provisioned_at
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.vm.hostname = 'UBUNTU-18-2'
  config.vm.provision 'shell', inline: $script
end
```

---

<sub>**NOTE:** the RabbitMQ team monitors the `rabbitmq-users` [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow.</sub>

Comment: What do you really mean by "Ubuntu 19.04 is code-named "Eoan Ermine""? The 19.04 is Disco Dingo, but 19.10 is Eoan Ermine...